# Anime movie where house has ghosts in it

Tags: story-identification, anime

I saw an anime movie where the main character lives in shacks or homes that have ghosts. The ghosts that the character sees are

> the houses. Each home or apartment has its own ghost. There is a necklace or pendent involved that helps the main character see house ghosts.

There might be a cat in it. IIRC The story takes place on the roof a building with shacks.

The name of the movie has House or Homes in the title.

Comment: Do you remember anything else? Roughly when did you watch this? Do you remember anything about the animation style? what language was it in? Do you remember any names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be the 2011 Korean film [The House](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt2408288/plotsummary/?ref_=tt_ov_pl), which is animated with photograph backgrounds?

> A woman living in a small house meets a cat and finds a special piece of jewelry allowing her to see the spirits of the house. Later, she finds it is up to her to prevent the city from tearing down her neighbors houses along with her own, and she needs the help of her new spirit friends.
> —Aiden Ottoson

According to reviewer [Rakestraw](https://letterboxd.com/film/the-house-2011-1/):

> It centers around Ga-young, who moves in with her friend in a rundown shantytown of sorts just across the way from the newly built luxury condos - Ga-young's dream home. Then the spirits are introduced, each individual home as a corresponding house spirit, which resemble something out of a Miyazaki film. The spirits need the help of the Land God, who happens to be a stray cat that teleports through an abandoned refrigerator to another universe, floating around on his armchair, organizing his trinkets and generally not giving a fuck about the fate of the house spirits.

Other reviewers say that it was formerly on Netflix.

Comment: This is it! Thank you